# How to integrate razorpay in flutter with firebase backend

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, razorpay

I already gone through plenty youtube videos and official razorpay documentation but none of them was complete on how to integrate it with **firebase**. All the tutorials I watched only included the half of it, also the official razorpay docs was not very clear.

The code is similar to this one https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-flutter/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart.
So, how to integrate it with flutter ? Any resource or tutorial with firebase integration would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone provide me with an answer ?

Comment: A useful article on razorpay integration https://vermahitesh.medium.com/razorpay-integration-in-flutter-web-a00dbc56bd17

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase Functions for creating your webhook and use the official  [razorpay_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/razorpay_flutter)

Comment: I already tried reading the docs. I have mentioned that in the question

Answer (score 0):

First you must have blaze plan to deploy firebase function. You can use this below firebase functions

1. To generate Order Id
2. To verify signature

Code

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const shortid = require('shortid');
const Razorpay = require('razorpay')
 
admin.initializeApp({});

const razorpay = new Razorpay({
  key_id: "key_id",
  key_secret: "secret key",
});


exports.getOrderId = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (context.auth == null) {
    return { data: [], status: 401, error: "Unauthorized" };
  }
  var options = {
    amount: data.amount, // amount in the smallest currency unit
    currency: "INR",
    receipt: shortid.generate(), //any unique id
    payment_capture: 1, //optional
  };
  try {
    const response = await razorpay.orders.create(options);
    return {
      data: {
        order_id: response.id,
        currency: response.currency,
        amount: response.amount,
      },
      status: 200,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return { data: {}, status: 400, error: "Unable to create order" };
  }
});

exports.verifyPayment = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (context.auth == null) {
    return { data: [], status: 401, error: "Unauthorized" };
  }

  let body=data.order_id + "|" + data.razorpay_payment_id;

  var expectedSignature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', "secret key")
  .update(body.toString())
  .digest('hex');
  console.log("sig received " ,data.razorpay_signature);
  console.log("sig generated " ,expectedSignature);

  if (expectedSignature == data.razorpay_signature) {
    return { data: {}, status: 200, error: "Success" };
  } else {
    return { data: {}, status: 400, error: "Failed" };
  }
});
```

After deploying, Now To integrate This function in Flutter you can use below codes

```
import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';
import 'package:pineapple/Utils/Utility.dart';

class FirebaseFunctionService {
  final FirebaseFunctions functions = FirebaseFunctions.instance;
  Future getOrderId(int amount) async {
    HttpsCallable callable = functions.httpsCallable('getOrderId');
    final res = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{"amount": amount});
    Utility.debugLog("getOrderId API Call Result =>" + res.data.toString());
    return res.data;
  }

  Future verifyPayment(
    String order_id,
    String razorpay_payment_id,
    String razorpay_signature,
  ) async {
    HttpsCallable callable = functions.httpsCallable('verifyPayment');
    final res = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
      "order_id": order_id,
      "razorpay_payment_id": razorpay_payment_id,
      "razorpay_signature": razorpay_signature
    });
    Utility.debugLog("verifyPayment API Call Result =>" + res.data.toString());
    return res.data;
  }
}
```

Finally you can call this function using below codes

```
  int selectedAmount = 100;
  int selectedCoins = 100;
  String selectedPlan = "";
  bool _isClicked = false;

  late Razorpay razorpay;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    razorpay = new Razorpay();
    razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_SUCCESS, handlerPaymentSuccess);
    razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_ERROR, handlerErrorFailure);
    razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_EXTERNAL_WALLET, handlerExternalWallet);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    razorpay.clear();
  }

  Future handlerPaymentSuccess(PaymentSuccessResponse response) async {
    print("Payment Success handler call : ${response.orderId} ${response.paymentId} ${response.signature}");
    final res = await FirebaseFunctionService().verifyPayment(
        response.orderId!, response.paymentId!, response.signature!);
    if (res["status"] == 200) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "Payment Success",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        textColor: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 13.0,
      );
      var resp = await UserServices().addCoins(selectedCoins);
      
      PaymentHistoryModel temp = PaymentHistoryModel(
        selectedPlan,
        selectedAmount,
        "",
        selectedCoins,
        widget.userdata.id,
        response.paymentId,
        response.orderId,
        DateTime.now(),
        "Success",
      );
      await PaymentHistoryService().addNewHistory(temp);
      print(resp);
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "Payment Error: Signature doesnot match",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        textColor: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 13.0,
      );
    }

    Routes.pop(context);
  }

  void handlerErrorFailure(PaymentFailureResponse response) async {
    print("Payment Error : ${response.code} == ${response.message}");
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: "Payment Error",
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      textColor: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 13.0,
    );
    if (response.code != 2) {
      PaymentHistoryModel temp = PaymentHistoryModel(
          selectedPlan,
          selectedAmount,
          "",
          selectedCoins,
          widget.userdata.id,
          "",
          "",
          DateTime.now(),
          "Failure");
      await PaymentHistoryService().addNewHistory(temp);
    }
    Routes.pop(context);
  }

  void handlerExternalWallet(ExternalWalletResponse response) {
    print("External Wallet ==> ${response.walletName}");
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: "External Wallet",
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      textColor: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 13.0,
    );
    Routes.pop(context);
  }

  void openCheckout({String paymentMethod = "RazorPay"}) async {
    print("------------------------------------");
    print(selectedAmount);

    final res =
        await FirebaseFunctionService().getOrderId(selectedAmount * 100);
    if (res["status"] == 200) {
      var options = {
        "key": Environment.razorpayKey,
        "amount": selectedAmount * 100,
        "name": "App Name",
        "order_id": res["data"]["order_id"],
        "description": "Payment ",
        "prefill": {
          "contact": widget.userdata.mobileNumber,
          "email": widget.userdata.email,
        },
        "external": {
          "wallets": [paymentMethod]
        }
      };

      try {
        razorpay.open(options);
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.toString());
      }
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "Payment Error: OrderId not generated",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        textColor: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 13.0,
      );
    }
  }
```

Now just call below function to start transaction

```
openCheckout();
```